# How to pivot table in dolphindb python api?

Tags: python, pandas, dolphindb

I have a dataframe like following in python:

```
  time                 A    B    C      D  E  F
0 2019-12-19 15:00:00  foo  one  small  1  2  2
1 2019-12-19 15:00:30  foo  one  large  2  4  4
2 2019-12-19 15:01:00  foo  one  large  2  5  5
3 2019-12-19 15:01:30  foo  two  small  3  5  5
4 2019-12-19 15:02:00  foo  two  small  3  6  6
5 2019-12-19 15:02:30  bar  one  large  4  6  6
6 2019-12-19 15:03:00  bar  one  small  5  8  8
7 2019-12-19 15:03:30  bar  two  small  6  9  9
8 2019-12-19 15:04:00  bar  two  large  7  9  9
```

How can I get the following dataframe by dolphindb python orca api?

```
E    2    4    5     6  8    9
A                               
bar  NaN  NaN  NaN   4  5.0  13.0
foo  1.0  2.0  5.0   3  NaN   NaN
```

The number in the dataframe means sum(D) in same A and E.

Answer (score 0):

In pandas, you can pivot a table by `pd.pivot_table(df, values='D', index='A', columns='E', aggfunc='sum')`. As for Orca, you just replace the `pd` with `orca`:

```
orca.pivot_table(df, values='D', index='A', columns='E', aggfunc='sum')
```

It returns the following DataFrame:

```
E     C2   C4   C5  C6   C8    C9
A
bar  NaN  NaN  NaN   4  5.0  13.0
foo  1.0  2.0  5.0   3  NaN   NaN
```

As you can see, the DataFrame has an extra prefix 'C' in its column names. This is because DolphinDB does not allow a column name starting with a digit.